# Symfony2 organize code used for ever page request

Tags: php, symfony

I'm programming my first site in symfony2, a site including some bundles for handling articles and static pages or contact page. I'e also created a bundle (backend only for now) for handling ads to show in the site, but this ads must to be shown in ever frontend page request, so I need to understand how to execute the necessary code to retreive the ads to show and pass this information at all the frontend controllers I have in mine bundles.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance
Robert

Answer (score 1):

Depends where do you keep your ads, but sounds like a job for [service container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html).

Basically you need to write a service that implements method to fetch the required ads and then call that service in the controllers (`$this->get('service_name')`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ads is only an example, I can have ads, multilevel menu, some sort of tracking like google analitycs. If I use a service, in ever controller I must get the appropriate service and use it, and if I want later to change something in this logic, I have to change the relative code in ever controller, and this violated the dry rules. I need only one place where set up page ads, menu and other, following by the right controller that set up only the content of the page.

Comment: I try to explain myself better: in the same way I have a base.html.twig that is common to all the frontend pages, I need an base controller that is common to all frontend pages.

Comment: Wait, why would changing logic in service should make you change code in all controllers? You have a single service that does all the fetching/menu generation/analytics fetch/whatever job for you and in Controller all you do is call it. So if some part of the logic must be changed, it's in the single service

Comment: Also if you need a "base" controller, you can just write it, have required code in it and then extend with others?

Comment: Changing logic in a service don't change code in all controllers, but if I need to add another common object in all pages I need to add this to all the controllers.

Comment: In ever case I just found wath I need in the official documentation:

<div id="sidebar">
    {% render "AcmeArticleBundle:Article:recentArticles" with {'max': 3} %}
</div>

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

See Embedding controllers within a twig template.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers

Basically if you want to include a global widget, you'll have to add it to the parent twig template in which your controller's template inherits.